# How to use ListFragment with BaseAdpater and Json file

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have a json which is displaying fine in a listview when using my customadapter which extends BaseAdpater.  in my tests, I can parse and inflate the listview perfectly fine when reading my json file when not loading  into a fragment.

I now need to move this/display it in a fragment.  My fragment is extending ListFragment.  I cannot get the listfragment to display.

This is the code for my fragment:

```
public class ActivitySearchResultsTwo extends ListFragment {

private ListFragment mListView;

public static ActivitySearchResultsTwo newInstance() {
    ActivitySearchResultsTwo fragment = new ActivitySearchResultsTwo();
    return fragment;
}

public ActivitySearchResultsTwo() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_session_row, null);
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayList<Sessions> sessionsList = Sessions.getRecipesFromFile("recipes.json",getActivity());
    SessionsListAdapter adapter = new SessionsListAdapter(getActivity(),sessionsList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    //getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

}

My listview is declared as follows:

```
  <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"/>
```

This is the relevant extract from my object class

```
public class Sessions {


public static ArrayList<Sessions> getRecipesFromFile(String filename, Context context){
    final ArrayList<Sessions> recipeList = new ArrayList<>();
```

// rest of my parsing of the json file....//

And finally my adapter listing....

```
public class SessionsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<Sessions> mDataSource;

public SessionsListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Sessions> items) {
    mContext = context;
    mDataSource = items;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

//1
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDataSource.size();
}

//2
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mDataSource.get(position);
}

//3
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

//4
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    // 1
    if(convertView == null) {

        // 2
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_session_row, parent, false);


        // 3
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        //holder.noOfPlacesTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.noOfPlaces);
        holder.remainingPlacesTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.remainingPlaces);
        holder.activityTimeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.activityTime);
        holder.activityPriceTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.activityPrice);

        // 4
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        // 5
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // 6
   // TextView noOfPlacesTextView = holder.noOfPlacesTextView;
    TextView remainingPlacesTextView = holder.remainingPlacesTextView;
    TextView activityTimeTextView = holder.activityTimeTextView;
    TextView activityPriceTextView = holder.activityPriceTextView;


    Sessions session = (Sessions) getItem(position);

    // 2
   // noOfPlacesTextView.setText(session.places);
    remainingPlacesTextView.setText(session.remaining + " / " + session.places + " Left");
    activityTimeTextView.setText(session.eventtime);
    activityPriceTextView.setText(session.price);

    // 3
    //Picasso.with(mContext).load(provider.imageUrl).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(thumbnailImageView);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView remainingPlacesTextView;
    public TextView activityTimeTextView;
    public TextView activityPriceTextView;
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated to get this list displaying in fragment.
Thanks

Comment: Please show us the Activity that contains  your Fragment. Also include the Layout of this Activity so we can see where you define your fragment or its place holder.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I did not update the onCreateView in my fragment activity with the list layout...I still had it set to show a previous layout i was using for test.

`View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_session_list, container, false);`

setting it as below solved my issue.

@ishmaelMakitla, thanks for your time on this topic